# How to remove trailing zeros after decimal but if it contains non-zero then keep as is

Tags: java

Using java(regex) how to strip float decimal having trailing zeros. If the decimal value contains non-zeros[1 to 9] then do not strip.

I tried using java replaceAll as below but its stripping all zeros even if there is non zero value after decimal

```
new Float(12.50f).toString().replaceAll("\\.0*$", "")
```

Ex:
 12.0 should trim to 12

12.5 should be 12.5

12.50 should be 12.50

12.000 should trim to 12

14.0056 should be 14.0056

Comment: Not sure why this question is marked as duplicate. I did not find answer to my original question. Ex If I have 12.6500 all other answers are trimming to 12.65 but It should not trim that. It must be just 12.6500. My question specifically says trim only if there are exclusive zeros after decimal.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `NumberFormat` to specify how to format your floating point numbers for display. There is no reason to use a regex here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick input. Can you provide any sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer but when I try with 12.50 it trims to 12.5